# What is the opposite of "busy schedule"?

Tags: word-request

What is the opposite of "busy schedule"? I read the forum at this [link](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2503982), and it says "loose schedule" is not a good choice. What is the common adjective for this?

Comment: According to your link, someone mentioned "my schedule is open". Perhaps, *a loose schedule* is too easy to be interpreted as *not a well-prepared schedule*. To me, *easy schedule*, *loose schedule* and *open schedule* can mean almost the same thing, i.e. the opposite of *busy schedule*.

Comment: I agree with DT; _open_ is a good choice. We can also say, "I'm pretty open next week" to mean "my _schedule_ is open next week." As an aside, I've been known to say, "My schedule is sparsely populated," but that was only in places where I could get away with sounding a bit odd or quirky; I wouldn't necessarily recommend that wording for day-to-day use.

Comment: @Lester: As you obviously know, "loose schedule" is not an idiomatic term. But in case you didn't realise, a ***tight schedule*** is more often used in contexts where there is *only just enough time* to meet the scheduled deadline for a project. It doesn't necessarily imply that any of the individual people working on it have full "appointment diaries".

Comment: How about "unbusy schedule"?

Comment: I would like to suggest "idle schedule" too.

Comment: Is “relaxed schedule” grammatically correct?

Comment: @Rupak, forgive the necro-comment, but yes, "relaxed schedule" is correct, idiomatic even, but it doesn't mean quite what the OP was after. "Relaxed schedule" is the opposite of "tight schedule", i.e. it means that tasks are allocated a generous amount of time and there are few strict deadlines. Like "tight schedule", it doesn't really imply anything about the calendars of the people involved.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Depends a bit on what you mean by "opposite", but the best choice is probably "**open**". "My schedule is open" means that, while you may have *some* things scheduled, they are few and far between, so it should be easy for you to fit something else in there.

"My schedule is **empty**" goes even further than "*open*": it means you have nothing planned.

"My schedule is **loose**" would be a way to say that your schedule is *flexible* (though personally, I would stick to the latter word in this context). In other words, you have things planned — perhaps lots of things — but you can move them around if needed. It's perfectly possible to be busy and flexible at the same time.

"I have an **easy** schedule for tomorrow" means that the things you have planned are all simple tasks that you will be able to complete without much effort. There is also some implication that at least parts of your schedule are *open*, because part of being *easy* is not having any time pressure. (Peeling a potato is a simple task if you have 10 minutes to do it. If you only have 30 seconds, suddenly it's a stressful & difficult activity.)

---

If what you're looking for is a way to say the opposite of "I'm busy", i.e. without the word "schedule" in there, then your best bet is to simply negate the statement: "I'm **not** busy".

Comment: 'Open' usually equates to 'empty.'  Otherwise, you'd run into issues like this: Person1: "How's your schedule tomorrow?" Person2: "My schedule is open." Person1: "Cool, how about lunch, say at 11:30?" Person2: "Oh, I've got something then, how about the next day?"

Comment: @MrWonderful, if Person2's schedule was really "open", his reply would be more like "Hm, 12:00 would work better for me."

Comment: You can also qualify it:  "My schedule is pretty open" = there are a few things on it but it should be easy to find a time that works for both of you, or "my schedule is wide open" = there are large stretches of un-allocated time.

Comment: @Martha, I can only comment on my own usage, but if I had something at 11:30, I would not have responded with "My schedule is open."  Instead, I may have said "I'm clear except for a meeting at 11:30," or, more likely, would have said "Light. Why, what do you have in mind?"  Thank you for keeping me honest! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Another way to say this is that you have lots of *free time*.

Answer (score 1):

I've also heard people aiming for a *relaxed schedule*, meaning there's lots of downtime between individual appointments, allowing for meetings to be extended or picking up something to eat in between.

However, the term could also be understood to refer to a loose schedule, eg. that coming 15-30 minutes late would be completely okay.

Answer (score 1):

"My schedule is light." That is the opposite of a heavy schedule. A *schedule* isn't busy, the *person* is busy. A schedule can also be described as "full", "clear", or "open".